# Wordpress 2024: ContactForm7 sending user to a php page with POST values

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form-7

I am new to wordpress but not to php programming. Yet I know very little of Javascript.

I am using wordpress 6.4.1 with theme twentytwentythree.

I have a form in ContactForm7 and I want to use it as a regular form, as in

> form action="ww.php" method="post"

ww.php will collect the data and form a string that will be passed to WhatsappWeb using curl. This is because the people who will process the data want to get it by Whatsapp, not by mail

I did my searches. I modified functions.php in my theme this way:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
{
    global $post;
    $id_to_change = 1857;
    if($post->ID === $id_to_change)
        return 'https://[domain]/ww.php';
    else
        return $url;
}

apply_filters( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
```

it gives "form action="https://[domain]/ww.php" method="post">" but it does nothing, it just sends the mail

Then I did this in functions php

```
function ti_custom_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
          document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
if ( '1856' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
    setTimeout( () => {
        location = 'https://[domain]/ww.php/';
    }, 3000 ); // Wait for 3 seconds to redirect.
    }
}, false );
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ti_custom_javascript');
```

(post ID is 1857, form ID is 1856)

This redirects the page but POST data is lost

I have read ways to keep POST data but I don't understand where to use them.

Thanks and forgive my bad English.

Comment: WordPress uses hooks and so does ContactForm7. What you're doing feels kinda "hacky". I'd suggest disabling the email notification in the settings and use the [wpcf7_posted_data](https://wpdebuglog.com/forums/topic/hooks-list-contact-form-7/) hook to retrieve data and submit it to Whatsapp.

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate you answer? Where do I use the hook?

Comment: I tested your function `wpcf7_custom_form_action_url` and the POST data was passed to my new form action URL (when `wpcf7_load_js` is disabled like you have).  At the same time... You can use the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook to pass data to a 3rd party API using wp_remote_post or wp_remote_get rather than `curl`

Comment: Thank you Howard. I solved it! I had to replace "apply_filters" with "add_filter"